# Is there a vim plugin or other program that copy-pastes a selected text to a permanent file in one keystroke?

Tags: linux, vim, clipboard

Is there a vim plugin or other program that copy-pastes a selected text to a permanent file in one keystroke? E.g. You select a text, do `Ctrl + s` and instead of copying to clipboard, it copies to a permanent file.

It can be via a vim plugin because I'll always do this action from inside a vim session. Ultimately I would want to first paste the relative path of the current file I'm in, then paste the selected text and then insert a blank line to separate for the next entry.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically a simple mapping:

```
:vnoremap <C-s> :write! >> file<CR>
```

To prepend the file name, I'd invoke an external command, though it could be done with `readfile()` / `writefile()`, too.

```
:vnoremap <C-s> :<C-u>execute '!echo "%" >> file'<Bar>'<,'>write! >> file<CR>
```

Comment: When I select a text in visual mode and do `:write! >> ~/myfile.txt<CR>` it works. But when I put `:vnoremap <C-s> :write! >> ~/mytext.txt` in my `.vimrc` and press `<C-s>` after restarting a vim session it doesn't do anything strangely.

Comment: Also, when executing `:<C-u>execute '!echo "%" >> ~/myfile.txt'<Bar>'<,'>write! >> ~/myfile.txt<CR>` after selecting a text I get an error message `trailing characters`, seems it's not correctly formatted.

Comment: The mappings must include the trailing `<CR>`, but if you type it as commands, instead of `<Bar>` type the literal `|`. Failure may also be due to your settings, see `:help map-special`.

Comment: I did `:noremap <C-s> :write! >> ~/Desktop/ho.txt<CR>` and `:noremap <special> <C-s> :write! >> ~/Desktop/ho.txt<CR>` confer to the example in `:help map-special`, still the same thing. Do you recognise anything in [my .vimrc](http://pastebin.com/v5Vbe3AM) that could interfere with this command?

Comment: No, looks fine. Can you try another key, e.g. `<F9>`? Maybe it's [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419820/sometimes-my-file-just-freezes-in-my-vi-vim-what-happened).

Comment: It looks like `<C-s>` was the culprit(and apparently also `<C-q>` did not work), I tried it with `Q` and both commands worked. Any idea how I can add a blank line in the file after each insertion?

Comment: Ah, glad you've found it! Another `!echo ""` should work for a blank line.

Comment: `:vnoremap Q :<C-u>execute '!echo "%" >> ~/Desktop/hi.txt'<Bar>'<,'>write! >> ~/Desktop/hi.txt<CR><CR><CR>:<C-u>execute '!echo " " >> ~/Desktop/hi.txt'<Bar>'<,'><CR><CR>:echo "Pasted!"<enter>` is the full command I was looking for. It skips the confirmation screen and shows a "Pasted!" message after you pasted your lines to that file.

Comment: Simply adding `!echo` does not work (`:vnoremap Q :<C-u>execute '!echo "%" >> file'<Bar>'<,'>write! >> file<CR>!echo ""<CR>`). But that's probably not what you meant. Anyway, with that command in my previous comment it does what I want, although I think that newline could be added in a less verbose as I wrote it. Thanks for your help!